# cascading dropdown in dynamic row angular?

Tags: angular, cascadingdropdown, formarray, cascading

I have cascading dropdown list which works alone, but when I generate a new row and change one of my dropdowns its affects my entire dropdown list.

Here is my html code.

```html
    <td>       
       <select class="form-control" formControlName="province_id" 
           (change)="onChangeProvince($event)">
          <option >Select Province</option>
          <option *ngFor="let province of provinces; let i = index" 
              [value]="province.id">{{province.province_name}}</option>
       </select>
    </td>
    <td>
       <select  class="form-control" formControlName="district_id">
          <option >Select District</option>
          <option *ngFor="let district of districts" [value]="district.id">
               {{district.district_name}}</option>
       </select>
    </td>
    <td>
       <button class="btn btn-danger"  type="button" 
           (click)="deleteMyRelation(i)">Delete</button>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" 
           (click)="addItem()">Add</button>
    </td>
```

Here is my component code.

```typescript
      createItem(): FormGroup {
            return this.fb.group({
              province_id: '',
              district_id: ''
            });
          }
        
       addItem(): void {
            this.itemRows = this.contactForm.get('itemRows') as FormArray;
            this.itemRows.push(this.createItem());
          }

       ngOnInit() {
            this.contactForm = this.fb.group({
              province_id: '',
              district_id: '',
              itemRows: this.fb.array([ this.createItem() ])
            });
            this.getProvinces();
          }

          provinces = <any>[];
          districts = <any>[];

          getProvinces(){
            this.contactService.getProvinces().subscribe(
              data => {
                this.provinces = data;
                console.log(data);
              },
              error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
          }
          onChangeProvince(event:any){
            
            this.contactService.getDistrict(event.target.value).subscribe(
              data => {
                this.districts = data;
              },
              error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need define each control with a `[formGroupName]='i'`. Now Angular will assign the values to each group properly, something like

```html
<table [formGroup]='contactForm'>
  <ng-container formArrayName='itemRows'>
    <tr *ngFor="let itemRow of itemRows.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]='i'>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" formControlName="province_id"
           (change)="onChangeProvince(i)">
          <option  value=''>Select Province</option>
          <option *ngFor="let province of provinces; let i = index" 
              [value]="province.id">{{province.province_name}}</option>
       </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select  class="form-control" formControlName="district_id">
          <option value=''>Select District</option>
          <option *ngFor="let district of districts[i]" [value]="district.id">
               {{district.district_name}}</option>
       </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger"  type="button"
           (click)="deleteMyRelation(i)">Delete</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"
           (click)="addItem()">Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

We can now define below functions to enable adding and removing of items

```typescript
  get itemRows() {
    return this.contactForm.get("itemRows") as FormArray;
  }
  deleteMyRelation(i) {
    this.itemRows.removeAt(i)
  }
  addItem(): void {
    this.itemRows.push(this.createItem());
  }
  onChangeProvince(i) {
    this.contactService
      .getDistrict(this.itemRows.get(i + ".province_id").value)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.districts[i] = data;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }
```

Now your form should work as expected

[**See Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rhlz2c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: my province_id is the foreign key in the district table, and the districts must be loaded based on province_id.

Comment: What I provided was a mock service. With the little information you have provided its practically impossible to help you. Could you share a stackblitz demo?

Comment: thank you, your information was excellent and my code is completely working, but the problem is that I have two tables province and district and the province id is the foreign key in the district table, when I change the last province of the drop-down list my all-district dropdowns are filling by the last province-related districts.

Comment: can you share your service code? especially `getProvince` and `getDistrict` functions

Comment: getProvinces()
  {
    return this.http.get(this.apiURL+ '/api/provinces/');
  }  getDistrict(province_id:any)
  {
    return this.http.get(this.apiURL+ '/api/district/' + province_id);
  }

Comment: Let me have a look

Comment: Please check the updated answer and stackblitz demo

Comment: Thank you so much, your code worked correctly.

Comment: Can you help me with the Edit of this form?

Comment: Sorry? Edit of which form?

Comment: I want to edit a record, I have used the following function in my component and I want to assign selected data into formArray.  ngOnInit() {
    this.contactService.getData(this.id).subscribe(res=>{
      this.itemRows = res;
     }) and this my function inside servivce. getData(id:number){
    return this.http.get(this.apiURL + '/api/contacts/edit/' + id);
  }

Comment: Hello, can you see my code for update it is not working correctly? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67396785/edit-cascading-dropdown-in-dynamic-row-angular

Answer (score 0):

Complementary the answer, when the only we need in a subscription use the values in the .html you can use pipe async.

You define

```
//It's usually way, named a variable that was an observable adding a "$" to the variable
province$=this.contactService.getProvinces()
district$=[]
```

As always we has a formArray is good has a getter

```
  get array(){
     return this.contactForm.get('itemRows') as FormArray;  
  }
```

Your (change) becomes like

```
  change(index)
  {
    const value=+(this.array.at(index) as FormGroup).get('province_id').value;
    this.array.at(index).get('district_id').setValue(null)
    this.district$[index]=this.dataService.getDistrict(value)
  }
```

You can use

```
   <select class="form-control" formControlName="province_id"
                  (change)="change(index)"  >
       <!--see that in selectProvince we put [value]="null" and hidden-->
      <option [value]="null" hidden>Select Province</option>
      <option *ngFor="let province of province$|async; let i = index" 
          [value]="province.id">{{province.province_name}}</option>
   </select>
   <select  class="form-control" formControlName="district_id">
      <option [value]="null" hidden>Select District</option>
      <option *ngFor="let district of district$[index]|async"
           [value]="district.id">
           {{district.district_name}}</option>
   </select>
```

I write a fool example in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uzamug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) (not has your models, but I hope can help for inspiration)